# c++ - having trouble in random numbers

Tags: c++, random

This program generates random numbers and lets the user guess it.
I'm using Geany as IDE and it highlights this as an error:
Error message: `error: 'rand' was not declared in this scope`

```
the_number = rand() % 101 + 1;
```

Code (not working):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
using namespace std;

int the_number;
int guess;
int tries=8;

the_number = rand() % 101 + 1;

cout << "Let's play a game!";
cout << "I will think of a number 1-100. Try to guess it.";
cout << endl;
cin >> guess;

for (tries = 8; tries++;)
{
    if (guess == 8)
    {
        cout << "You guessed it!";
        cout << "And it only took you: "<< tries;
    }
    else if (guess < the_number)
    {
        cout << "Higher";
        tries++;
    }


    else if (guess > the_number)
    {
        cout << "Lower";
        tries++;
    }

    else
         cout << "That's not even in range!";
    return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: And what does the error say? Is it only the IDE that complains? Does it build? What happens if you include the correct [header file](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib) that declares [`rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand)?

Comment: If something doesn't work you should [look it up](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand).

Comment: if (guess == 8), so you always win when you guess 8 xD

Comment: Looks like it is wrong: for (tries = 8; tries++;)

Comment: By the way, you might want to take a look at that loop of yours, which *could* go on for a very long time before it will give you *undefined behavior*. Luckily for you, it will only run once before you exit the program.

Comment: It said: **error: 'rand' was not declared in this scope**

Comment: The manual for future reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the include for cstdlib. Here is a minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::cout<<rand()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```